# Python / tkinter / classes - object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, class, tkinter, self

The code at the bottom of this post creates multiple tabs inside a ttk Notebook. All was well when I created each tab with four lines of code like this:

```
edit_frame = ttk.Frame(workbench)
edit_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
edit_frame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1) 
workbench.add(edit_frame, text='     Edit     ')
```

I wanted to reduce the repetition and created the class TabFrame. This creates the tabs that I wanted, but throws up errors as soon as I try to place anything in a tab. (If I create the edit tab with the four lines that are commented out, rather than creating an instance of TabFrame, it works fine.)

The Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/pi/Desktop/VDDS/vdds_min.py", line 40, in <module>
edit_text_frame = ttk.Frame(edit_frame)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/ttk.py", line 742, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2262, in _setup
self.tk = master.tk AttributeError: 'TabFrame' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

The Thonny Assitant says :

```
AttributeError: 'TabFrame' object has no attribute 'tk' __init__.py
line 2262 Your program tries to access attribute tk of an object of type 'TabFrame', but this type doesn't have such attribute.
```

and warns as :

```
Line 7 "self = ttk.Frame(notebook)": Invalid assignment to self in method
```

I'm quite new to Python and now totally stumped as to what these error messages are telling me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TabFrame:
    """a frame used in each tab of the root """
    def __init__(self, notebook, text):
        self = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        notebook.add(self, text= text)

root = tk.Tk()

# configure root
root.title('Voltmace Database development system')
root.geometry('800x600+300+300')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.configure(bg='#888')

# create Notebook
workbench = ttk.Notebook(root)
workbench.grid(sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S, padx=5, 
pady=5)
workbench.enable_traversal()

# Create tabs

edit_frame = TabFrame(workbench, ' EDIT   '   )
# edit_frame = ttk.Frame(workbench)
# edit_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# edit_frame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1) 
# workbench.add(edit_frame, text='     Edit     ')

assemble_frame = TabFrame(workbench, ' ASSEMBLE   '   )
dump_frame =  TabFrame(workbench, ' DUMP   '   )
debug_frame =  TabFrame(workbench, ' DEBUG   '   )
help_frame = TabFrame(workbench, ' HELP   '   )

# EDIT tab
edit_text_frame = ttk.Frame(edit_frame)
edit_text_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
edit_text_frame.grid(sticky='ew')
ttk.Label(edit_text_frame, text='This feature is not yet 
implemented.').grid(sticky='we', padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot assign ```self``` to the Frame. Instead try something like. ```self.f1=ttk. Frame```

Comment: It looks like you are thinking of classes the wrong way. Try looking at class intermittence and make `TabFrame` inherit from `ttk.Frame`.

Comment: Thank you @TheLizzard. That got me asking the right questions and found the answer at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

changed the class and it works:

class TabFrame(ttk.Frame):
    """a frame used in each tab of the root """
    def __init__(self, notebook, text):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, notebook)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        notebook.add(self, text= text)